# Compling Gearman Error - storage size uuid unknown

Tags: c, gearman

Trying to compile gearman on Suse 10 and I get this:

```
#:~/src/gearmand-0.14> sudo make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/src/gearmand-0.14'
  CC     libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-client.lo
libgearman/client.c: In function '_client_add_task':
libgearman/client.c:986: error: storage size of 'uuid' isn't known
libgearman/client.c:1002: warning: implicit declaration of function 'uuid_generate'
libgearman/client.c:1003: warning: implicit declaration of function 'uuid_unparse'
libgearman/client.c:986: warning: unused variable 'uuid' [-Wunused-variable]
make[1]: *** [libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-client.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/src/gearmand-0.14'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the source file in question:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gearman-developers/gearmand/trunk/annotate/head:/libgearman/client.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> storage size of 'uuid' isn't known

I guess you're missing an `#include` in client.c.

Comment: line 14 client.c: #include "common.h"
Common.h:64 15 
#ifdef HAVE_UUID_UUID_H
65  
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
66  
#endif

Comment: Is `HAVE_UUID_UUID_H` defined by that point of the compilation process? Can the compiler include the contents of the header `<uuid/uuid.h>` (note it's enclosed in `<>` and that the search for it is not the same as if it was encolsed in `""`)? Is `uuid` defined by that header?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about C to answer those questions with any level of certainty.

Comment: I think you need the `libuuid` library installed. According to [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid) it is part of the `e2fsprogs` package.

Comment: I thought that was installed, apparently the headers are missing. Thanks!